# Add text to a cell above based on cell color

Tags: vba

I am a beginner, and I need to add the word "Core" above any cell that has the background color index 47.
The part I cannot get is in the loop, stating from top to bottom, the row counter minus one. This is what I have so far. The problematic row seems to be the forth one.

```vb
Dim r as range
For each r in range("A1:A10").rows
If r.interior.colorindex=47 then
Cells(r-1,"A").value="Core"
End If
Next r
```

Comment: Two things: there is no ros above row 1, so run yout loop from A2.  r is a range, not a number,  so `Cells(r-1,"A")` won't give you what you expect.   Use `r.Offset(-1, 0)`

Answer (score 0):

2 major errors:

1. The minimum row number of the range should be 2 because you want to print the word above the row.
2. r is a range object, you want to check a cell color index value so you should choose each of the cells of the range

Here´s the code after the correction:

```
Sub add_text_based_on_color()

Dim r As Range

For Each r In Range("A2:B10").Rows

    For Each cel In r.Cells
    
        If cel.Interior.ColorIndex = 47 Then
        
            Cells(cel.Row - 1, cel.Column).Value = "Core"

        End If
    Next cel
Next r


End Sub
```